# How to prepare data for bulk insert in scala slick 2.1.0

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I'm using Slick 2.1.0. I'm trying to perform `insertAll` from a case class.

The structure of case class is

```
case class ClassA(field1: Int, field2: ClassB)
case class ClassB(field3: String, field4: String)
```

There's a function `def bulkInsert(param: List[ClassA])`
I tried this approach approach.

```
val data = param.map( p => (p.field1, p.classB.field3, p.classB.field4))

dbTable.map(e => (e.field1, e.field2, e.field3))
.insertAll(data)
```

But I'm getting error

```
Required: Tuple
Found: List
```

What shall be done to fix this issue

Comment: What is the `data` signature? Is it `Seq` of tuples of raw data?

Comment: `param` is the list of Case Class. For e.g.
`data` is the mapped off of `param` field so it's also a List of provided mapped field